# i want to display this result using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have a table named exam_time_table. i want to get the time table of each class. i tried to get the result.but its not getting.

controller

```
public function index()
    {
       $this->load->model('exam_model','exam');
           $data['exam_data']=$this->exam->select_data();
           $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
```

Model

```
public function select_data() {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('exam_time_table');
        $this->db->group_by('extt_std');
        $query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
       }
```

View

```
<?php
foreach($exam_data as $exam)
{
echo $exam->extt_id;
echo $exam->extt_sub;
echo $exam->extt_date;
}

?>
```

[image: this is my table][image: want output like this]

Comment: Unclear question Can you explain what you want actually

Comment: Please tell what is the error .

Comment: i want output like that above table. of each class

Comment: @saleena how you get array data. post data array using `print_r` method

Comment: @AbdullaNilam can you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you have two model class than load like

```
   $this->load->model(array('exam_model', 'exam'));
```

or load separate

```
  $this->load->model('exam_model');

  $this->load->model('exam');
```